# create two pointers for template class and work with current selected possible?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

I'll try showing what I want with an example code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class myclass
{
    public: 
        myclass(int x, int y);
        // code
};
        
main()
{
    myclass<cat>* ptr1 = NULL;
    myclass<dog>* ptr2 = NULL;

    if (/*condition*/)
    {
        ptr1 = new  myclass<cat>(1,1);
        delete ptr2;
        current_ptr = ptr1; // how to declare
    }
    else 
    {  
        ptr2 = new  myclass<dog>(1,2);
        delete ptr1;
        current_ptr = ptr2; // how to declare
    }
    current_ptr->some_method(); //work with it
}
```

I want use template class with different arguments. How do that?

Comment: Why is `myclass` template? What are `cat` and `dog`? Are they related to each other? Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are a compile time construct. When the template is instantiated, it creates unrelated classes.

As such, `myclass<cat>` and `myclass<dog>` are totally different, unrelated classes with you cannot exchange pointers between them.

To mix them up at runtime, you need some form of runtime polymorphism. The simplest is when you know all types in advance, then you can use variants:

```
#include <variant>

int main() {
    std::variant<myclass<cat>, myclass<dog>> obj;

    if (/* runtime condition */) {
        obj = myclass<cat>{};
    } else {
        obj = myclass<dog>{};
    }

    // work with it:
    std::visit(
        [](auto const& myclass_obj) {
            // in here, myclass_obj is either a myclass<cat> or myclass<dog>
            // So the code has to be valid for both, unless using if constexpr.
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(myclass_obj), myclass<cat> const&>) {
                // cat specific code
            } else {
                // dog specific code
            }
        },
        obj
    );
}
```

If you want to continue with pointers, you need a base class:

```
class mybase {
public:
    virtual ~mybase() = default;
    virtual someMethod() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class myclass : public mybase {
public:
    myclass(int x, int y) {}

    void someMethod() override {

    }
};
```

Then declare your pointer:

```
mybase* ptr = nullptr;
```

Comment: but what if it's a large ready-made library? https://github.com/Makuna/NeoPixelBus

Comment: Then you must use a polymorphic wrapper, such as `std::variant` or your own.